# Where is the Krogan DMZ?

Tags: mass-effect-3

One of the side missions has the goal of rescuing mercenaries from the Dranek system, inside the Krogan DMZ. None of the clusters in the galaxy map show that mission under the name, so which cluster/mass relay should I jump to in order to complete this quest?

Comment: I haven't gotten this far yet, so not an answer, but it should be near Tuchanka.  I thought the sector itself was named 'Krogan DMZ'.

Comment: @Shinrai Tuchanka is a planed inside the Krogan DMZ system.

Comment: @kotekzot - Yes, that's my point.  Tuchanka's in the Aralakh system - both Aralakh and Dranek are in the Krogan DMZ.

Comment: @Shinrai Ah, pardon, I missed the context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Krogan DMZ is directly below the Serpent Nebula (which houses The Citadel).

[image]

Comment: I now think I have to do something before I go there. That mass relay (along with about four others on your screenshot) are not on my galaxy map.

Comment: I just confirmed that the Krogan DMZ does not appear on the galaxy map until after rescuing the Krogan female from the Salarian compound